# Error in loop with python

Tags: python, loops

I have list `lst = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 3, 5, 3]` and to every iteration, where `elem == 3` I want to print strings before that, while elem not is 3 again.
I want to get

```
2 3:
0 1
1 2
6 3:
3 4
4 5
5 6
8 3:
7 5
```

But I don't know, how to go to previous string

```
for i, el in enumerate(lst):
    if lst[i] == 3:
        print i, el
        i -= 1
```

But it's inly `elem-1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
    lst = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 3, 5, 3]
    previous = []

    for i, el in enumerate(lst):
        if lst[i] == 3:
            print i, el,":"
            for p in previous:
                print p[0] , p[1]
            previous = []
        else:
            previous.append((i,el))
```

Comment: How can I continue, if `lst[i-1] == 3?`

Comment: not sure I understand? you can use the keyword 'continue' to move to the next iteration of the loop. But I guess you know that?

Answer (score 1):

You might try implementing with slices as in:

```
lst = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 3, 5, 3]

start_pos = 0
for idx, val in enumerate(lst):
    if val == 3:
        print idx,val,":"
        for p_idx, p_val in enumerate(lst[start_pos:idx]):
            print p_idx+start_pos,p_val
        start_pos = idx+1
```

Comment: How can I continue, if `lst[i-1] == 3`?

Comment: I'm not certain what you are asking. Can you provide an example?